# Loopback Multitenancy and different models

Tags: multi-tenant, loopback

We have started to develop a multi-tenant application. Each tenant will have a different database and the main database for users and roles. I have tried the multi-tenancy strategy and can bind different schema at run time.

Now the problem is each tenant will have common models like people, interactions, etc but the columns in each can differ. Also, we can add new tables. Is it possible to create model columns dynamically based on the requesting tenant and also controllers for new tables dynamically?

Is there an example application on this? Any help is greatly appreciated.